# Get element by class name and attribute value and set CSS in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a directive:

```
class LkfsSliderDirective {

constructor() {
    this.restrict = "E";
    this.templateUrl = "./controls/lkfsSlider/lkfsSliderTemplate.html";
    this.controller = 'LkfsSliderController';
    this.controllerAs = 'slider';
    this.replace = true;
    }

    link(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
}

export default LkfsSliderDirective;
```

In HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" class="lkfs-slider-slide" alt="" id="{{slide.id}}" ng-repeat="slide in slider.slides"/>
```

I would like get `img` tag by class name with specific id (for example = 0) and set CSS (`display: block`).

I tried in many ways but nothing works, for example:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
angular.element(elem).css('display', 'block');
```

Also in link.

Any ideas?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the element with the specific ID using `document.getElementById()`:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("0");
angular.element(elem).css('display', 'block');
```